# Google Maps - canvas custom overlay zoom

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, browser

As you can see at:
http://rolls.mit.edu/

I am doing the following:

1. create a map

   ```
   map = new google.maps.Map(mapContainer, options);
   ```
2. add overlay

   ```
   overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
   overlay.draw = function() {};
   overlay.setMap(map);
   ```
3. add canvas to overlay

   ```
   overlay.getPanes().overlayLayer.appendChild(canvas);
   ```

Everything works well except when I zoom, the canvas remains the same size. Is it possible to zoom the canvas when you zoom in/out? Any pointers to examples?

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen to the [google.maps.Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) zoom_changed event, get the new zoom level from the map (with map.getZoom()), then resize or modify your canvas element appropriately.

If you just want to draw a line, look at the [google.maps.Polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polyline) overlay, that has the zoom functionality built in.

Comment: I used a line to illustrate the point. I am actually doing a custom animation. I'll test with idle and the zoom event. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much have to render a new canvas for whatever google zoom levels you want to support.  The way I have addressed this is by setting a listener on the "idle" event for the map. This will fire once the map goes idle after a zoom or pan.  Then you can determine if the zoom level has changes and act accordingly.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(mapContainer, options);
var zoomLevel = 6; //some defaut

var handleBoundsChanged = function(){
   var oldZoom = zoomLevel;
   var zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
   if( zoomLevel != oldZoom){
       rebuildOverlayForZoom(zoomLevel)
     }
}


google.maps.event.addListener (map, 'idle', handleBoundsChanged);
```

Comment: Thanks @robododge, that makes sense. I was hoping the layer was a little smarter. I'll listen to the event and make the change by hand.